# Changing background alpha values to all the div's at once

Tags: html, css

I want to add same alpha value to all the div's in my web page. These div's are of different background colors, and i don't want to set value in 'rgba' because i may want to revert.

Something like this:

```
div{
    background-color: rgba( , , ,0.8);
}
```

well this is not working, any ideas?

Comment: `i don't want to set value in 'rgba' because i may want to revert`. If you are going to use `rgba()`, you'll have to fill in each part. If you don't like the end result, you could always set the alpha transparency to `1.0`.

Comment: I'm assuming you want all the transparent value to be 0.8 or at least the same value throughout the divs? While you can't have empty values in rgba, you can use a variable for the transparency part if you are familiar with LESS / SASS. rgba (200,200,200,@opacity). When you change the variable, all the values using the @opacity variable will change.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply opacity to divs but elements inside it (another div or paragraph tag, anything) will be same opacity unless been defined otherwise. If you think you can have rgba(null,null,null, 0.4); Good luck doing that!

If you need to apply to all DIV elements then this should work for you and it's browser compatible as well.

```
div {
  zoom: 1;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  -moz-opacity:0.6;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason for vendor prefixes and filter. The browser support for opacity is excellent: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity

Comment: I disagree for Chrome starts from version 29 and FF from 24. CSS I provided covers most browser compatibility issues even for IE7! and early versions of Safari.

Comment: This is not true. If you would've checked the link I posted you would know that. opacity is _atleast_ supported since FF 2.0, Chrome 4.0, even partial support in IE 5.5 is there. Most projects don't need IE7 support.

Comment: Opacity is chain applied, and cumulative (so to speak). If you set div {opacity: 0.6;} and you have a div inside a div inside a div, it will have an opacity of 0.2 (or so). If you have a div nested in 5 levels of divs, it will be almost invisible.

Comment: Apologies for disagreeing with you but in my defence sometimes we develop apps for National Health organisations and trust me IE7 and below compatibility is must.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be useful:

```
var alpha = 0.4;
$("button").click(function () {
    $div_array=$("div");
    for(var i=0; i<$div_array.length; i++)
    {
        var val_array = $("div").eq(i).css('background-color').match(/^rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/);
            $("div").eq(i).css('background-color', "rgba(" + val_array[1] + ", " + val_array[2] + ", " + val_array[3] + ", "+ alpha +")");
            console.log($("div").eq(i).css('background-color'));   
    }
});
```

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZu42/)**.